# keydown event is not working for "Alt" key?

Tags: c++, firebreath

I am doing a project using firebreath framework. I am firing the keydown event for a plugin.
For all other keyboard keys, the keydown event is working properly. But only for the "Alt" key it does not get fired.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If your javascript can trap the alt-key event, maybe you can delegate it to plugin.